# How to use MinMaxScaler on all columns?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Right now, I have my data in a 2 by 2 numpy array. If I was to use MinMaxScaler fit_transform on the array, it will normalize it column by column, whereas I wish to normalize the entire np array all together. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation it seems you cannot change the axis of the MinMaxScaler. One alternative is to define a scaling function based on the definition of the MinMaxScaler, from the documentation:

```
X_std = (X - X.min()) / (X.max() - X.min())
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

So you can do it like this:

```
import numpy  as np

X = np.array([[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6]])


def min_max_scale(X, range=(0, 1)):
    mi, ma = range
    X_std = (X - X.min()) / (X.max() - X.min())
    X_scaled = X_std * (ma - mi) + mi
    return X_scaled

print(min_max_scale(X))
```

**Output**

```
[[0.         0.42857143]
 [0.07142857 1.        ]]
```

Basically you need to drop the axis parameter, to consider the maximum and minimum from the whole array.

Comment: Well that's exactly the same as what MinMaxScaler already does isn't it, scale the data column by column. Instead what I'm looking for from your example would be for -1 to be scaled to 0 and 6 to be scaled to 1 since -1 is the smallest value in the np array and 6 is the largest

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the original MinMaxScaler API in a following way:

1. reshape X numpy array to one-column array,
2. Scale,
3. Reshape results back to the shape of X array

   ```
   import numpy as np

   X = np.array([[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6]])
   scaler = MinMaxScaler()
   X_one_column = X.reshape([-1,1])
   result_one_column = scaler.fit_transform(X_one_column)
   result = result_one_column.reshape(X.shape)
   print(result)
   ```

**Output**

```
[[ 0.          0.42857143]
 [ 0.07142857  1.        ]]
```